# Find record whose date range includes a given date?

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, date

I have a list of pay periods in a database and need to find a record based on a given date.

For example, pay period #26 is for the date range October 13, 2013 through October 26, 2013.

If I passed `October 17, 2013` I'd want it to find the row for pay period #26 in the database.

For what it's worth, I'm using Ruby and the database is Postgresql.

```
== Table: pay_periods ==
period:integer
start_date:date
end_date:date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your date is stored in `date` local variable, this should work:

```
PayPeriod.where('start_date <= :date AND end_date >= :date', date: date)
```

Comment: For some reason, that's not working. For instance, searching for today's date returns nothing. But there's definitely a record for it: `#<PayPeriod id: 25, period: 25, start_date: "2013-11-27", end_date: "2013-12-10">`

Comment: Oh wait, I see *why* it's not working (start date is less than today's date)...but not sure how to get around that.